# Java - Adding constraints

Tags: java, if-statement, constraints

I have made this class for fun, and now I want to add some constraints and if statements. But don't know how.

**Problem 1)** I don't know how to do an if statement on System.out.print outputs. Say, if the user enter more than 50 characters then they'll be stopped.

I know how to do this in MySQL but not in Java as I'm very inexperienced ATM. :|

**Problem 2)** I also want to restrict myself from entering digits if it's nextLine, or text if it's nextInt.

Can anyone help me on these two problems?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class AppForm {
   public static void main(String args[]){

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter your name... ");
      System.out.println("Your name is " + sc.nextLine());

      System.out.print("Enter your age... ");
      System.out.println("Your age is " + sc.nextInt());

   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: consider reading a java book, please dont post a question for every detail you dont know. Learn java first, and then we are more than happy to answer your questions

Comment: @sleimanjneidi is there any book you can recommend? I tried a few but none so far really helps me. A book contain steps would be beneficial, as I'm someone who learn by looking at answers. The books I've read asked me to solve their questions and don't provide answers is really difficult for me to truly grasp their purpose. I don't mean to post here, but here the community really aided me so far in understanding Java more than my books. Hope you can understand.

Comment: Thinking in java is my favorite book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by breaking apart the input and output code by storing the result of `nextLine()` in a variable:

```
System.out.print("Enter your name... ");
String line = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Your name is " + line);
```

You can then perform any check you need on the `line` string variable. The typical paradigm in the case of an interactive program is to print out an error message and ask the user to repeat the entry in case of invalid input:

```
System.out.print("Enter your name... ");

String line = sc.nextLine();

while (line.length() > 50) {
    System.out.println("Error: you entered more than 50 characters");

    // Ask the user for their name again...
    System.out.print("Enter your name... ");
    line = sc.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("Your name is " + line);
```

Unfortunately there is no way to prevent the user from typing invalid characters - you can only check the content of the line *after* the user has finished typing and your program receives the typed line.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend at taking a look at while loops.
Some possibilities:

```
String name;
do {
    System.out.print("Enter your name... ");
    String line = sc.nextLine();
while (StringUtils.isEmpty(name) || name.length() > 50)
```

Or:
String name;

```
while (StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
    System.out.print("Enter your name... ");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    if (name.length >= 50) {
        System.out.println("Max name length is 50");
    }
}
```

But there are plenty of flow control options.